# TSQL retrieve backup date from database after restore

Tags: t-sql, backup, restore, cloud

Usecase: MSSQL Database is hosted in the cloud, I download the database thrue FTP and restore it on-premise automatically for reporting.

Now I want to retrieve the date/time when the backup was made, from the restored database, to show my users how old the data is that they are working with.

In my local MSDB, I only see when the database was restored, not when it was originally back-upped in the cloud. I know the date-time is in the .bak, but that is hard to query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Found it eventually, but not thrue Google :-)

Comment: Found it, but not thrue Google:
[code]
select top 1 s.backup_finish_date
from msdb.dbo.backupfile f 
left outer join msdb.dbo.backupset s on s.backup_set_id = f.backup_set_id
where f.logical_name = '<name of mdf-file>' 
order by f.backup_set_id desc [/code]

Comment: Hi boogjan, welcome to the site. I'm glad you found the answer to your question but on this site you are encouraged to type it in the answer box instead of in a comment. You can even accept your own answer by clicking the green check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer from author's comment converted to community wiki*

```
select  top 1 
        s.backup_finish_date 
from    msdb.dbo.backupfile f 
left outer join 
        msdb.dbo.backupset s 
    on  s.backup_set_id = f.backup_set_id 
where   f.logical_name  = '<name of mdf-file>' 
order by 
        f.backup_set_id desc
```

In case the original MSDB is not available, or backup history has been purged, the data is available within backup headers. Use [`RESTORE HEADERONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to retrieve the header contents. In the header, there's about 60 pieces of metadata; refer to the Microsoft documents for detailed description.

For example,

```
restore headeronly from disk = N'<path-to-backup-file.bak>';
```

Comment: In case the original server's MSDB is not available, one could use [RESTORE HEADERONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to check backup's headers.

Comment: @vonPryz This is a community wiki answer. Feel free to add any information you find useful into the answer itself.